# is it possible to add a specific code to body of methods listed in jparepository of spring data jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data, implementation

How can I add a specific code in the implementations of methods that are listed in jparepository of spring data jpa without creating a new method in an interface that extending jparepository.
I want to edit the body of some methods listed in jparepository.
for example in save method body:
add[system.out.println("before persisting");] just before calling persist method
and [system.out.println("after persisting");] just after a persist calling
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce some aspect. It will provide you implement whatever you want.
You can see similar example here
[Spring AOP + JPARepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046532/spring-aop-jparepository)
Something similar to this

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Configurable
public class AuditLogAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository+.save(*))")
public void whenSaveOrUpdate() {};


@Before("whenSaveOrUpdate() && args(entity)")
public void beforeSaveOrUpdate(JoinPoint joinPoint, BaseEntity entity) {...}
```

}